Google sheets ArrayFormula to create a check register
Google sheets
I am trying to use an arrayformula to add the D cell of my previous row, to the C cell of my current row and place the result in my current row D cell. Basically it is a check registry So if I am on row 2, the formula for D2 would be D3+C2.  I cannot get a formula that does not give me a #REF in D2.  Any ideas?

I want to use an ArrayFormula so that if I insert a row somewhere, it will automatically copy the formula into it.
Thanks
I tried using ChatGPT and it gave me some ideas using row offsets, but I still got the REF error.

Recommendation: Use Custom Function
As this is somehow complex when using Google Sheets Formula, you may want to use Google Apps Script in creating a custom function.
Script
function balance(amountList, currentBalance) {
  amountList.reverse().shift(); //reverses data arrangement and removes unwanted data
  var out = [];
  amountList.map(w=>w.map(x=>{
    currentBalance += x; //cummulative balance
    out.push([Number(currentBalance).toFixed(2)]);
  }))
  return out.reverse(); //returns the output
}

Usage / Function Syntax
For this custom function, I decided to get the amount column and current balance as inputs. The custom function syntax should look like this:

=balance(amountList, currentBalance)

In the case of your example, I assumed that 972.89 is the current balance. Hence, I used the following formula for D2:

=balance(C2:C10,D10)

Which should look like this:

References:

Custom Function

Update:
If D2 is made to be the reference for the custom function, the script should look like this:
function balance2(amountList2, currentValue2) {
  amountList2.pop()
  var out = [];
  amountList2.map(w => w.map(x => {
    currentValue2 -= x;
    out.push([Number(currentValue2).toFixed(2)]);
  }))
  return out;
}

The custom function will still have the same paramaters but with different target range as shown below:

This output assumes D2 to be the starting value of the function so the formula is placed in cell D3.

Current Balance is D2

I see. But what will D2 still be the basis of the starting value for the function? As far as I see it, the pattern of your data goes from bottom to top (based on your time stamps).

I can modify the script as long as the data in D2 (if d2 will become the reference) is constant and the formula will be placed on D3.

@mysticbt I have added an update to my answer with the assumption that D2 is the current balance (based on your comment). Kindly check if this works for you.

Using the SCAN formula, this can be done by entering the following formula in ce  D3
=SCAN(G2,C2:C10, LAMBDA(row,val,row-val))

.

You have to enter the current/start balance in cell G2 and zero (0) values in cells C2 and D2 as starting values.

You can see the sample table and the results in the image below.

Note that; the data is in range C3:C11 but in the SCAN formula we are using C2:C10. If your data in Column C will be growing, you can use the range as C2:C1000


.


Thanks I will give it a try...
